# Is it safe to give write permission to index.php file?

Tags: php, hacked-site, lighttpd, directory-index

Today I accidentally gave write permission to my `index.php` file to using `sudo chmod +x index.php`. I don't know what permission it had before.

My `index.php` contains a php script for collecting number of visitors and an another script for collecting referrer links. It also contains some pictures and css code and my webserver is Lighttpd

Did I made a mistake by giving `index.php` that permission? Can my website be hacked for it?

Comment: If hacker will able to reach till index.php then changing permission is not a big task for hacker. show your code `contains a php script for collecting number of visitors and an another script for collecting referrer links`. Generally Keeping permission `0644` is safe. Only Owner can write

Comment: Questions about programming are off topic here. You should delete this and, instead, ask on https://stackoverflow.com/ https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: How are file permissions programming?  If this were asked on SO, I think it  would get closed it because there is no code involved.  SO does have a relevant question for 2010 though: [What permissions for PHP scripts/directories?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2096255/what-permissions-for-php-scripts-directories)